# Adding and removing click/hover event handlers jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, event-handling

Run into issues mixing click and hover events.

Clicking an inactive li a element toggles an active class and binds a hover event.
Hovering over now active element displays a previously hidden block (span.rate)
Clicking the hovered element is supposed to hide it, remove hover event and toggle the active class on the parent so it is no longer 'active'.

Clicking the hovered event does not remove the events and toggle active. There is some other logic in there regarding mutually exclusive options, this all works fine though.

jsfiddle of how it all sits together:

http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/15/

Current js:

```
ps = {

psToggle: 0,

init: function () {

   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.example li a)').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var that = $(this);
            if (that.parent().hasClass('paired')) {
                if (rm.psToggle === 0) {
                    that.toggleClass('active');
                    that.find('.rate').fadeToggle(50);
                    rm.psToggle = 1;
                } else {
                    if (that.hasClass('active')) {
                        that.toggleClass('active');
                        that.find('.rate').fadeToggle(50);
                        rm.psToggle = 0;
                    } else {
                        $('.paired a').toggleClass('active');
                        that.find('.rate').fadeToggle(50);
                        //Call message function
                    }
                }
                rm.pControl();
            } else {
                that.toggleClass('active');
                that.find('.rate').fadeToggle(50);
                rm.pControl();
            }
        });

    });

},

pControl: function () {

    //Unbind events to all control items excluding 1st item. 
    $('.example li a').off('hover');
    $('.example li a .rate').off('click');

    $('.example .active').each(function(i) {
        $(this).on('hover', function() {
            $(this).find('.rate').fadeToggle(50);
        });
    });

    $('.example li a.active .rate').on('click', function() {
        //Remove hover/hide and toggle active state
        $(this).off('hover');
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
        rm.pControl(); //rebind new active classes
    });

}
```

};

ps.init();

Comment: your fiddle does not working

Comment: There are many errors in your code.

Comment: jsfiddle is now working, typo fixed. Any suggestions around adding/removing the hover events?

Comment: Use browsers console you will see a error regarding the non existence of `rm.pControl()` I think thats needed be changed to `ps.pControl()` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/12/)**,  let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks sorry, lots of typos... the jsfiddle is now accurate to how this functions in the larger project. http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/15/

When you click on the green hover block, it should hide it, unbind the hover event and remove the active class from the parent. This is the actual issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below demos.

Both the click events were getting fired as ,`.rate` is the child of `a`.

`$('.example li a.active .rate').on('click'...`   and

`$('.example li a').on('click'...`

- So you can either remove the click on `.rate`. **[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/17/)**
- Or add `e.stopPropagation();` to the child to stop event bubbling from parent to child. **[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/18/)**

  ```
  $('.example li a.active .rate').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      //Remove hover/hide and toggle active state
      $(this).off('hover');
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
      ps.pControl(); //rebind new active classes
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/10/)Correct

```
$('.example li a') instead of $('.example li a)')
```

update [here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/65yY3/10/)